# Работа с ассоциативным массивом Map

Tags: java, map, коллекции

Есть задание: нужно организовать работу с ассоциативным массивом на java с использованием Map. А именно, есть 2 файла с записями: типа ключ и значение.  Ключ нужно вывести в 3 файла, результат по ключам 2 и 5. Как создать мапу разобрался, но как считать данные с файлов, именно так, чтобы сначало записывались ключ-значение, а после считывания файла, запись следующего в обратном порядке. Ведь при объявлении мапы задается тип ключа и содержимое в нем, но сначала это число и буква, а потом во втором файле буква, число вот файлы и данные:

`1.txt`

```
1 a
2 v
3 f
4 g
```

`2.txt`

```
k 6
b 3
n 5
m 7
```

`result.txt`

`2 5`

```
package task;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class task1_collections {
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream out;
    String line;
    Map<int, String> map1 = new HashMap<int, String>();
    Map<String, int> map1 = new HashMap<String, int>();

}
```

еще еклипс ругается и не позволяет задать целое и стринг. а только стринг и стринг как считать с файлов в мапы так и не розобрался

Comment: файл задан в столбец

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Files
            .lines(Paths.get("1.txt"))
            .map(str -> str.split(" "))
            .forEach(value -> map.put(Integer.valueOf(value[0]), value[1]));
    Files
            .lines(Paths.get("2.txt"))
            .map(str -> str.split(" "))
            .forEach(value -> map.put(Integer.valueOf(value[1]), value[0]));
```

Comment: а куда собственно записиваются значенния в мапе послендовательно или же как подмапа?

Comment: и что ето за Files?

Comment: HashMap<Integer,String>map <- это хэш таблица, содержащая ключ - типа Integer и значение типа String. В данной структуре данных значения не упорядочены. Каждая строка из файла бьется на две строки, которые потом приводятся к нужному типу и записываются в мэпу.  java.nio.file.Files -  это класс, в котором есть статический метод lines

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно по вопросам.

1 - нельзя использовать примитивы (`int`), нужно использовать обёртку (boxing) над ним (`Integer`).

2 - из файла просто так в map прочитать нельзя. Если этот файл был получен сиреализацией, тогда это возможно, а иначе - читать построчно. Примерный код:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
             map.put(Integer.valueOf(sCurrentLine), br.readLine);

    } catch (Throwable e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (Throwable ee) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: для второго файла повторить операцию з записью в ту же мапу или использовать уже вторую мапу?

Comment: судя по вашей логике - вторую.